# Is this a valid definition of $\Delta$ complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, simplicial-complex

I am trying to understand what delta complexes are: Is the below definition correct?

$X\text{ is a }\Delta\text{-complex if }X=\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty X^i\text{ where }X^i=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A_i}\Delta_\alpha\text{ where }\Delta_\alpha\approx\Delta^i \text{such that }\forall\Delta_\alpha\in A^i,\Delta_\beta\in A^j,~\exists\Delta_{\gamma_1}\in X^{k_1},\ldots\Delta_{\gamma_n}\in X^{k_n}:~\Delta_\alpha\cap\Delta_\beta=\Delta_{\gamma_1}\cup\ldots\cup\Delta_{\gamma_n} $

Here $\Delta^i$ is the standard i - simplex. In the simplicial complex the above definition works with $n = 1$.

I don't get how this is related to this formal definition:

A $\Delta$ complex is

1. For $ n \geq 0$, a sequence of sets $\{X_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$
2. For each $n>0$ each $ 0\leq i \leq n$, a map $d_i: X_n \rightarrow X_{n-1}$
   such that
3. For each $0\leq j < i \leq n$ with $n > 1$, $d_i \circ d_j = d_j \circ d_{i+1}$

If someone could explain what is the correspondence between the two definitions or where the first definition fails with an example would be very helpful for me.

Comment: When you write $\Delta^\alpha\in X^i$ is that supposed to be $A_i$ instead of $X^i$?

Comment: In any case, your first definition is far too weak and allows all sorts of horrendous things.  For instance, you could take $X$ to be any space at all, where each point is a $0$-simplex.

Comment: @EricWofsey thanks for pointing that out. I have edited to reflect that